# In Windows power shell, how do you extract a properties file value and save it to an env var?

Tags: powershell, makefile, windows-10, environment-variables, properties-file

I have a properties file with entries like the below ...

```
...
USERNAME=myuser
...
```

In my Makefile, I have the below which uses Unix like commands to get the value of the variables ...

```
export USERNAME=$(shell grep USERNAME my_properties.txt | cut -d'=' -f 2-)
```

However, in a Windows power shell (maybe command prompt is the right phrase?), the above doesn't work because "grep" is not a standard command (among others).  What's the equivalent way to extract a property from a properties file in a Windows power shell environment?

Comment: Thanks for accepting; turns out the `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` was unnecessary, but `-NoProfile` is advisable - please see my update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `cmd.exe` is the default shell:

```
export USERNAME=$(shell powershell -noprofile -c "(Select-String 'USERNAME=(.+)' my_properties.txt).Matches.Group[1]")
```

<sup>Note: `-NoProfile` suppresses loading of PowerShell's profiles, which unfortunately happens by default. Should you need the `-File` parameter to execute a *script file*, you may additionally need `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`, unless your effective [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) allows script execution.</sup>

The above uses the PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)'s `-c` (`-Command`) parameter to pass a command that uses the [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) cmdlet, PowerShell's `grep` analog.

---

A closer analog to your command would be the following, which additionally uses `-split`, the [string-splitting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) (showing the raw PowerShell command only; place it inside the `"..."` above):

```
((Select-String USERNAME my_properties.txt) -split '=', 2)[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

We could achieve this in PowerShell by following the below steps

1. Read the contents of the file
2. Convert the contents into key-value pairs
3. Create environment variable with the required value

(*you can combine the steps if you like, I've kept them separate for better understanding*)

Here's the script

```
$content = Get-Content .\user.properties -raw
$hashTable = ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData $content
$Env:USERNAME = $hashTable.USERNAME
```

Comment: @mklement0 's answer which uses 'select-string' and 'split' provides a closer equivalent of the 'grep' and 'cut' commands